# Vertica PlannedConcurrency

Tags: concurrency, vertica

I have been trying to tune the performance of queries running on a Vertica cluster by changing the value of PlannedConcurrency of the general resource pool. We have a cluster of 4 nodes with 32 cores/node. 
According to Vertica docs,

> Query budget = Queuing threshold of the GENERAL pool / PLANNEDCONCURRENCY

Increasing PlannedConcurrency should reduce the query budget, reserving lesser memory/query which might lead to fewer queries being queued up.
Increasing the value of PlannedConcurrency, seems to improve query performance.

PlannedConcurrency = 256 gives better performance than 128 which performs better than AUTO.

PlannedConcurrency being the preferred number of concurrently executing queries in the resource pool, how can this number be greater than the number of cores and still give better query performance?

Also, the difference between RESOURCE_ACQUISITIONS.MEMORY_INUSE_KB and QUERY_PROFILES.RESERVED_EXTRA_MEMORY should give the memory in use.
However, this number does not remain constant for a single query when the planned concurrency is changed.
Can someone please help me understand why does this memory usage differ with the value of PlannedConcurrency ?

Thanks !

References:
https://my.vertica.com/blog/do-you-need-to-put-your-query-on-a-budgetba-p236830/
https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.1.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/AdministratorsGuide/ResourceManager/GuidelinesForSettingPoolParameters.htm

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to give an exact answer without the actual queries.
but, in general - increasing the planned concurrency means you reserve and allocate less resources per query and allow for greater concurrency.

If your use case has lot's of small queries which don't require lot's of resources - it might improve things.

also keep in mind that the CPU is not the only resource being used - you have to wait for IO (disks, network etc') this is time you can better spend on running more queries...

Comment: How do i get to know the actual memory usage for a query? @cohenjo

Comment: The  use case involves mostly large queries with joins on multiple (at least 2-3) tables.

Comment: @singsuyash - as stated in the question the difference between the acquisition and extra memory shows what's in use.

BhaviJagwani - what's the reserved_extra_memory values? you should see them shrink as you increase concurrency.
(large/small are relative terms - if you have extra resources then for your cluster these are not large queries :) )

Comment: @cohenjo, yes, the reserved_extra_memory values do shrink as I increase the concurrency. But isn't that because the query_budget decreases as plannedConcurrency increases. How does the difference between the two values not remain constant (or nearly constant)? How does the value of essential memory vary widely ?

Comment: yes, as you increased the planned concurrency the reservation decreases - so less extra memory reservation.
but it also means that there is room to run more queries - this will effect throughput (- I'm guessing this is the main performance gain you see.)
and also it will effect your acquisitions (because the load on the machine should grow...)